# Microsoft Teams Graph api - getting call id

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm testing some scenarios with Microsoft Teams Communications api (via Graph API), but I got stuck with one thing. I would like to retrieve participants from particular call, but I don't know from where can I get call id for existing call (scheduled by the user)? I have tried to get Id's from meeting url, but without success. Can you help me from where can I take call id to below request?

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/{id}

Comment: If you see the [Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1) below myparticipantsId there is id which is call id.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply, but I was asking about existing calls for example created by another user. Is it possible to retrieve the list of calls for example with their ID?

Comment: you can check [Get call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-getting-a-group-call) API to retrieve call object.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT to make [Get call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-getting-a-group-call) request you have to provide Call ID. How to know Call ID first?

Comment: Whenever you create a call using cloud communications API you will get the call id in response please see this [sample code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/blob/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/HueBot/HueBot/HueBot.cs)

Answer (score 0):

The call-id is generated when your code joins a call or receives an event a call has started. This can be done via a number of API calls.

One example is if you create a chatbot that can join calls.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot

Comment: is there any other option to get the current call id inside an in-meeting Teams app?